# How to catch click on link in chrome devtools on elements tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to have ability to catch the click on stylesheet sourcemap link (_body.styl like in example below) and redirect to custom protocol (subl:// for example to open in sublime editor). Is there any way to create devtools extension for this?

Or maybe I can somehow to edit the [chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.js](http://chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.js) directly (it would be ok for me because I want to create my internal tool)?

[image: Chrome devtools style block]

Comment: did u mean that if you click the body.styl:1, you will copy the whole css?

Comment: No, I configured the chrome workspace and I just want to open sublime with linked to source file.